# Andriod Studio with Kotlin for connecting the main_activity page to the layout pages

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

I have different fragments on the activity_main.xml page which takes in buttons/fragments from BottomAppBar. The OnNavigationItemSelectedListener and the R.id.bottom_.. ids do not work and I am not sure how to fix it. My layout for each fragments are also labeled bottom_home, bottom_message,...

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val onNavigationItemSelectedListener =
        BottomAppBar.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.bottom_home -> {
                    replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.bottom_message -> {
                    replaceFragment(MessageFragment())
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.bottom_shelf -> {
                    replaceFragment(ShelfFragment())
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.bottom_account -> {
                    replaceFragment(AccountFragment())
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navView: BottomAppBar = findViewById(R.id.BottomAppBar)
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)

        // Set the initial fragment
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
        }
    }

    private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
            .commit()
    }
}
```

I want it to build on the device but none of my layout pages are loaded on the andriod phone in andriod studio because the main acitivity is not working.